# C++ BitField class with variadic template and parameters pack

Tags: c++, templates, bit-fields

I'm trying to implement a BitField template class for C++11/14, my base idea is:

```
template <typename T, size_t... Bits>
class BitField
{
    public:

        BitField();

    private:

        T value;
};

template <typename T, size_t... Bits>
BitField<T, Bits...>::BitField()
{
}
```

and then as an example instantiate it like this:

```
BitField<uint8_t, 2, 3, 3> bitfield;
```

where 2, 3, 3 are the sizes of the 3 bitfields, offsets come consequently (please let's ignore bit order by now).

Of course this is just a skeleton to be filled with appropriate setters and getters methods, now my question is: how can I get Bits values in the constructor to check if their sum fits the type, possibly at compile time?

More in general, can this be a good approach for this problem? I say other solutions but for many reasons I don't like them too much.

Thanks, Matteo

Comment: not sure what "the 3 bitfields" are, but have you checked whether std::bitset (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) wouldn't do the job?

Comment: Thanks, I checked it but I need something different.

Answer (score 0):

You can check size with (C++17)

```
static_assert(sizeof(T) == (Bits + ...));
```

Before [fold-expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) of C++17, there are workaround more verbose.

Create a function

```
template <std::size_t... Bits>
constexpr std::size_t sum()
{
    const std::size_t numbers[] = {Bits...};
    // std::accumulate in constexpr only since C++20
    std::size_t res = 0;

    for (auto number : numbers) {
        res += number;
    }
    return res;
}
```

and then

```
static_assert(sizeof(T) == sum<Bits...>());
```

You can even use lambda instead of helper function if wanted.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still on C++ 14, is it possible to do something similar? Moreover, how can I get single values of parameters in constructor?

Comment: C++14 version added. (c++11 version would also be possible, with recursion).

Comment: *"how can I get single values of parameters in constructor"*. I don't understand your question. (Maybe another question might be asked).

Comment: For example in a for-loop or similar get 2, 3, 3.

Comment: The C++14 code iterate over the number (after put them in array).